# Group all rows after 4 rows and create 5th row of grouped rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, case, oracle12c

I have a Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT WORKING_DAYS, ACTIVITY
  FROM TABLE
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(ACTIVITY)
  FOR ACTIVITY IN (
     6 AS NL6,
     7 AS NL7,
     8 AS NL8,
     9 AS NL9,
    11 AS NL11
  )
)
ORDER BY WORKING_DAYS;
```

Output of the above query is as below:

[image]

I was trying to have output as below but I am having no clue how to proceed:

[image]

Can anyone help here and let me know best possible solution for this?

I am using Oracle version - 12.1.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `WORKING DAYS` to your desired format in the sub-query before you `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN WORKING_DAYS <= 4
         THEN TO_CHAR( WORKING_DAYS )
         ELSE '>4'
         END AS working_days,
         ACTIVITY
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(ACTIVITY)
  FOR ACTIVITY IN (
     6 AS NL6,
     7 AS NL7,
     8 AS NL8,
     9 AS NL9,
    11 AS NL11
  )
)
ORDER BY WORKING_DAYS;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( working_days, activity ) AS
SELECT  1, 6 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 6 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 9 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 6 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 6 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 8 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 6 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 8 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 6 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 6 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 8 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 9 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 8 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 8 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 24, 9 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 25, 7 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> WORKING_DAYS | NL6 | NL7 | NL8 | NL9 | NL11
> :----------- | --: | --: | --: | --: | ---:
> 1            |   2 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0
> 3            |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0
> 4            |   0 |   0 |   0 |   2 |    0
> >4           |  16 |   1 |   6 |   2 |    0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6798787218aa801f148020883659e3a7)*

Answer (score 0):

That's easier done with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    case when working_days > 4 then '> 4' else to_char(working_days) end as working_days,
    sum(case when activity =  6 then 1 else 0 end) nls6,
    sum(case when activity =  7 then 1 else 0 end) nls7,
    sum(case when activity =  8 then 1 else 0 end) nls8,
    sum(case when activity =  9 then 1 else 0 end) nls9
    sum(case when activity = 11 then 1 else 0 end) nls11
from mytable
group by case when working_days > 4 then '> 4' else to_char(working_days) end
```